# git push still issues RPC error after changing postBuffer

Tags: git, http

So since I'm using Webfaction, I followed [their git tutorial](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/git.html), and have run this on my git instance:

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Just to be clear, here's what's in the `config` of my repo:

```
$ cat config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = true
[http]
    receivepack = true
    postBuffer = 524288000
```

Regardless, this still happens:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 74, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (62/62), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 3.67 MiB | 962 KiB/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The wacky thing is that I'm not even pushing up that much data: only about 120MB.  Now I'm still quite new to git, so I thought I might post my local `.git/config` file too:

```
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@MY.DOMAIN.TLD/REPONAME.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Honestly, I'm completely out of ideas.  If someone can see what I've done wrong, I'd really appreciate it.  Note that I know I can do this over SSH, but that's not ideal for my scenario.

Comment: Why not use the ssh or git protocols?

Comment: Well SSH would require that I allow people other than me to have SSH access to read/write the repo.  Not an option.  And I don't know how to access it via the git protocol.  But HTTP *should* work right?

Comment: You can limit access through ssh. Have a look at gitolite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after some blind tweaking (and some sleep) I realised that the problem was actually *where* I ran the postBuffer command.  I ran it on the repo end, and not on the client side.  Once I ran it client-side everything worked just fine.

Sorry to confuse everyone.